# Having a bit of trouble with getting google sheets to auto update time in multiple columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Having a bit of trouble with this code. It's meant to auto-input the time a cell in 2 specific columns was updated to the right of the cell. It was working with the script for just one of the cells being triggered on edit, but not when I put them into a function so I could have more than one running at once.

```
function onEdit(e){
 myFunction1();
 myFunction2();
}
function myFunction1()
{
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Dispatch Log")
  {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Time Dispatched") + 1;
    var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("Dispatched to Location") + 1;
    if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == orderCol)
    {
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"));
    }
  }
}
function myFunction2()
{
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Dispatch Log") 
  {
    var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Time 1") + 1;
    var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf("Status 1") + 1;
    if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == orderCol)
    {
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"));
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm rather new to java script

Comment: `Hint:` next time, when you will be posting a question on SE, please also paste the error message you are getting (for javascript it will be usually in a browser console). It will help find the root cause quicker than when analyzing only a code sample.

Comment: You need to explicitly pass function parameters. Review variable scope in JavaScript on your preferred developer documentation resource.

Comment: I wasn't getting an error message that I could see, it was just that nothing was happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass your event `e` as a function argument.

```
function onEdit(e){
  myFunction1(e);
  myFunction2(e);
}
function myFunction1(e)
{
  ...
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: I'm kind of embarrassed that it was something that simple. That worked, thanks much!